# NativeScript: is there a way to retrieve the binary data and process it after being read from file?

Tags: javascript, nativescript

This question is NativeScript related.

I want to process the binary data after being read from file.
I followed the official doc here:

[file-system#readingwriting-binary-data-fromto-a-file](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/file-system#readingwriting-binary-data-fromto-a-file)

with this, I can successfully read and write (in other word: "copy") the binary files. What I'm trying to accomplish now is to process the binary data ( it could be any sort of binary data, eg. image, database, etc... ) and then save it in file. But I can't figure out how to retrieve the raw binary data from a variable object returned by ***readSync***, please have a look at the code below (btw currently testing on ios environment):

```
var source = sourceFile.readSync(e=> { error = e; });
console.log(typeof source.bytes);
console.log(typeof source.length);
console.log(source.bytes);
console.log(source.length);
```

When I execute this code, I see the these messages in console log:

```
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/views/login/login.js:99:12: object
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/views/login/login.js:100:12: number
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/views/login/login.js:101:12: <Pointer: 0x11da02000>
CONSOLE LOG file:///app/views/login/login.js:102:12: 1720728
```

From this output I surmise that ***source.bytes*** is a pointer object and not an array object... My question is: is there a way to store the data into array, possibily in Uint8Array type?

Comment: Have you created a service for read and write ? can you share it ?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution to make it work on ios environment. It was written in the source code:

[**NativeScript**: objc!Foundation.d.ts](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/0197505e1db99a4397364bb929de16b0bea850c5/tns-platform-declarations/ios/objc-i386/objc!Foundation.d.ts)

So, use getBytes() to retrieve the data into array abject. 
**Example code:**

```
var arr = new ArrayBuffer(source.length);
source.getBytes(arr);
var uint8arr = new Uint8Array(arr);
```

Comment: For Android you need to do `var uint8arr = new Uint8Array(source);`, skipping the ArrayBuffer.